# ¿que falla al momento de enviar los datos con retrofit al api en SLIM?

Tags: android, webservice, retrofit

Hola estoy trabajando con retrofit 2.3.0 y slim v2, y al momento de enviar los datos por medio de retrofit no se me devuelve el json que se tiene que recibir y posiblemente ni siquiera  envía los datos del formulario , ya que otra funcion de la api si me funciona

archivo de endpoints (interface retrofit)

```
public interface apiAdapter {


    @POST("login/{usuario}/{password}/{googleId}/{idDispositivo}")
    Call<resultado> login(@Path("usuario") String usuario,@Path("password") String password,@Path("googleId") String googleId,@Path("idDispositivo") String idDispositivo);

    @POST("guardarForm/{ubicacion}/{contrato}/{inicial}/{final}/{total}/{bobina}/{usuario}/{servicio}/{orden}")
    Call<resultado> guardarServicioForm (@Path("ubicacion") String ubicacion,@Path("contrato") String contrato,@Path("inicial") String inicial,@Path("final") String finl,@Path("total") int total,@Path("bobina") String bobina,@Path("usuario") int usuario, @Path("servicio") int servicio,@Path("orden") int orden);




    @GET("login2")
    Call<resultado> mensaje();




}
```

este el archivo que gestiona el json q recibe

```
public class resultado {
    @SerializedName("estatus")
    @Expose
    private String estatus;

    public String getEstatus() {
        return estatus;
    }

    public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
        this.estatus = estatus;
    }
}
```

y el codigo siguiente es el  parte de la funcion  donde hago click para enviar el formulario

```
Retrofit retrofit2 = new ApiConfigRetrofit().consultas();
            apiAdapter servicio = retrofit2.create(apiAdapter.class);
            //persona pepe = new persona(email,password,"dfgf","dfgfd");
            Call<resultado> llamada = servicio.login("sdfs","password","fdgf","dfdgf");
            llamada.enqueue(new Callback<resultado>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<resultado> call, Response<resultado> response) {

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getEstatus(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<resultado> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

y este es el error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: appstda.erp.com.mx.siga40, PID: 10401
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String pruebasEjemplos.resultado.getEstatus()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at LoginActivity$4.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:237)
                                                                               at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede en tu caso es que estas recibiendo respuesta del servidor pero no es la que esperas, el body del response viene nulo en la siguiente linea

```
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getEstatus(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Cuando entras en el método onResponse de tu retrofit quiere decir que la conexión con el servicio web fue exitosa, sin embargo puede suceder que no te retorna el objeto que esperas y por el contrario te retorna un código con el error y un mensaje, para evitar que tu aplicación se rompa y para ver que es lo que está sucediendo deberías el siguiente cambio

```
Retrofit retrofit2 = new ApiConfigRetrofit().consultas();
            apiAdapter servicio = retrofit2.create(apiAdapter.class);
            //persona pepe = new persona(email,password,"dfgf","dfgfd");
            Call<resultado> llamada = servicio.login("sdfs","password","fdgf","dfdgf");
            llamada.enqueue(new Callback<resultado>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<resultado> call, Response<resultado> response) {

                    if (response.body() != null) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getEstatus(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if(response.code() != null) {
                        Log.d("Error", String.valueOf(response.code()) + response.message());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<resultado> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Recuerda revisar el log de android studio para que sepas cual es el error que hay al enviar los datos, quiza puede ser que tu modelo "resultado" difiere a lo que esperas en el servicioweb ( el nombre del atributo por ejemplo ).

Comment: Muchas gracias   me sirvió  de mucho tu comentario

Comment: JesusSh si te sirvio mi respuesta porfavor puntuame, espero que todo vaya bien